# Applying a filter to open form macro in Access 2013

Tags: forms, vba

I've been asked by one of the departments in our School to create a database in which they can store and filter data with ease.

It's been a long time since i've used Access and I can't seem to remember or find a way to create a working Macro that Applies a filter to a form it opens.

I have a table set up called Main_Data with a Column called 'Class'. That is the data I am wanting to filter and be shown when the form is opened. The form that is being opened and filtered is 'Reading Student Entry Form'.

I am using the form builder at the minute and have it set up as follows:

> Form Name: Reading Student Entry Form
>
> View: Form
>
> Filter Name:
>
> Where Condition: [Main_Data]![Class]='class1'
>
> Data Mode: Edit
>
> Window Mode: Normal

Ideally when it runs I would like it so that the user can enter what class they want to apply to the filter as this method seems as though I am going to have to create several different macro's for each class and then assign them to command buttons.

Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

Copy this code in your private module of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'
  Dim strClass
  strClass = InputBox("Please type the class name:", "Class Input", "class1")
'
' not to open the form as no class given:
'  
  if(IsEmpty(strClass)) then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
  end if
'
' filter by class name:
'  
  Me.Filter = "Class='" & strClass  & "'"
  Me.FilterOn = True
'
End Sub
```

I suggest you also rename your form:

```
Form Name: Reading Student Entry Form => frmStudentEntry
```

Avoiding space in form names is always a good pratice.